# Would an extra gigabit ethernet card improve server performance

Tags: performance, gigabit-ethernet

my setup is the following:

**TP-Link TL-ER5120 Gigabit Load Balance Router**

The router has 2 WANs and 3 LANs connected to it:

- LAN 1 Cable goes to a **TP-Link SG-1024 Gigabit Switch (24 gigabit ports)**
- LAN 2 Cable goes to a wireless router
- LAN 3 Cable 3 goes to a wireless router

So, my server is currently connected to the gigabit switch via 1 cable. The server is used by about 20 people for project management and ownCloud (file sharing).

Would it improve performance to add another gigabit ethernet card and connect it to the switch on another port?

NOTE: The load balancer sends all port 80 and 443 requests to the IP that the current network card has. If I add another card I wouldn't be able to redirect traffic from port 80 and 443 to it I think.

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: Are you saturating a single link?

Comment: It depends. Where are you seeing performance issues?

Comment: `Would it improve performance to add another gigabit ethernet card and connect it to the switch on another port?` - Does a performance problem actually exist?

Comment: The server uses Ubuntu 16.04

I am not sure if I am saturating but when about 20 people are connected at the same time it tends to get slow, the thing there is that I am not sure whether it's processor related or network related. The PC has a 4th-gen Core i5 and 8 gb ddr3 ram.

Comment: You are supposed to identify the bottleneck *first* and then think about how to widen it. Not the other way around.

Comment: I don't consider this being a duplicate, I just asked if it would increase performace or it wouldn't have any positive effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would an extra gigabit ethernet card improve server performance?

## No

If the server is low on CPU or Memory, has slow disks or the application is crap etc. then adding more bandwidth won't improve a thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Would an extra gigabit ethernet card improve server performance?

## Yes

If lack of bandwidth is your bottleneck.